# EF Core InMemory database initialization throwing System.NullReferenceException exception in unit test cases

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use in-memory database for testing my efcore project and [followed this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory).

Below is my setup:

```
    public class Student
        {

            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            public string LastName { get; set; }

         }


    public class StudentContext : DbContext
    {
       public StudentContext(){
       }
        public StudentContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Student> Student { get; set; }
    }


 [TestClass]
    public class StudentTest
    {
        private StudentContext _dbContext;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Setup()
        {
            var optionBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<StudentContext>();
            var options = optionBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase().Options;
            _dbContext = new StudentContext (options);
            _dbContext.Users.Add(new Student
            {
                Id = 1,
                FirstName = "tester",
                LastName = "tester",
            });
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ValidateStudent()
        {
            var service = new StudentService(_dbContext);
            var response = service.AddStudent(new Student{
                Id = 2,
                FirstName = "tester2",
                LastName = "tester2",
            });
            Assert.IsTrue(response);
        }


        [TestCleanup]
        public void Cleanup()
        {
            _dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            _dbContext = null;
        }
    }
```

It is throwing System.NullReferenceException at the below line :

```
var optionBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<StudentContext>();
```

The only reason it is showing in the stacktrace is as below :

```
threw exception. System.NullReferenceException: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..
    at StudentContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.InitializeServices()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_StateManager()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.EntryWithoutDetectChanges[TEntity](TEntity entity)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState[TEntity](TEntity entity, EntityState entityState)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Add[TEntity](TEntity entity)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
```

I am not able to find the reason for this error.

Comment: as you've mentioned, you are using the docs...have you seen the `OnConfiguring` method in the docs? by your stacktrace, the error is in this method...you probably need to override it to handle it better. (I've never work with InMemoryDataBase and I'm completely newbie about .net core, but by the error and the example in the docs...you missed this `OnConfiguring` part...check it again.

Comment: Another thing...in your controller you declare `public StudentContext(DbContextOptions options)` and by looking at the docs should be `public StudentContext(DbContextOptions<StudentContext> options)`

Comment: Thanks Elmer, I ignored OnConfiguring method because due to the Note above that code snippet which says "If you are using ASP.NET Core, then you should not need this code" . But since i am running testcases outside of the efcore context i need it which automatically solved the issue.

Comment: Nice! Good coding!